# Enterprise Library Logging Block Rolling Flat File Not Writing to File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-web-api, enterprise-library

I'm implementing a multi-tier web solution using ASP.NET MVC 5 for the web stack and WebApi 2.2 for the back end services stack.  These will be on different servers when deployed, but running in two different processes locally for development - Windows 7 and IIS 7.5.  I'm trying to implement a Rolling Flat File trace listener in both processes with Enterprise Library 6 Logging Application Block.  I have a common project that contains my Log class that will hold onto its own singleton instance of itself - where all access to the Logger will be:

```
public sealed class Log : ILog
{
    private static readonly Log m_log;

    static Log()
    {
        var factory = new LogWriterFactory();
        Logger.SetLogWriter(factory.Create());

        m_log = new Log();
    }

    private Log() // no one else can create
    { }

    public static ILog Instance { get { return m_log; } }

    public bool IsLoggingEnabled()
    {
        return Logger.IsLoggingEnabled();
    }

    public void Critical(object caller, string method, string message)
    {
        if (Logger.IsLoggingEnabled())
            Write(caller, method, message, TraceEventType.Critical);
    }

    public void Error(object caller, string method, string message)
    {
        if (Logger.IsLoggingEnabled())
            Write(caller, method, message, TraceEventType.Error);
    }

    public void Warning(object caller, string method, string message)
    {
        if (Logger.IsLoggingEnabled())
            Write(caller, method, message, TraceEventType.Warning);
    }

    public void Information(object caller, string method, string message)
    {
        if (Logger.IsLoggingEnabled())
            Write(caller, method, message, TraceEventType.Information);
    }

    private void Write(object caller, string method, string message, TraceEventType severity = TraceEventType.Information)
    {
        var entry = new LogEntry();
        entry.Severity = severity;

        if (Logger.ShouldLog(entry))
        {
            entry.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            entry.Message = message;

            entry.ExtendedProperties.Add("Type", caller.GetType().Name);
            entry.ExtendedProperties.Add("Method", method);

            ...

            Logger.Write(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration that is exactly the same for both processes, with the exception of the file name being written to (MVC writes to Web.log and WebApi writes to WebApi.log):

```
<loggingConfiguration name="loggingConfiguration" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
<logFilters>
  <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.LogEnabledFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
      enabled="true" name="Logging Enabled Filter" />
</logFilters>
<listeners>
  <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
    fileName="C:\Logs\WebApi.log"
    footer="" formatter="Text Formatter" header=""
    rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Midnight"
    timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-DD" maxArchivedFiles="7"
    traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack"
    filter="All" />
</listeners>
<formatters>
  <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
    template="Timestamp:{timestamp} Severity:{severity} Message:{message} Machine:{machine} ProcessId:{processId} ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{dictionary( {key}:{value})}"
    name="Text Formatter" />
</formatters>
<categorySources>
  <add switchValue="All" name="General" autoFlush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </add>
</categorySources>
<specialSources>
  <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </allEvents>
  <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </notProcessed>
  <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </errors>
</specialSources>
```

The WebApi stack is using Unity to do DI for all controller dependencies.  My singleton instance is getting properly resolved and injected onto my ApiController base class that all my controllers are deriving from.  I have an action filter that is trying to write to the log in both onActionExecutingAsync and onActionExecutedAsync events.

Here's the problem: The WebApi process is not writing entries to the WebApi.log file.  The process creates the file; it's just not writing anything in there. I'm fairly sure I had something writing in there to begin with, but I just can't get it to log anything there anymore.  I've stepped through the debugger, IsLoggingEnabled() returns true, and the Logger.Write method gets called.  I've tried undoing all refs to the Logging Block in the front end, thinking that there were issues running the block in multiple processes on the same machine. No change.  The front-end MVC process is creating and logging to the Web.log file just fine (again, same configuration).  Anyone have any clues as to what I'm missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Configuration looks OK.  Trying changing this line to: `entry.ExtendedProperties.Add("Method", method ?? String.Empty);`

Comment: Thanks for looking so quickly.  I tried what you mentioned to no avail. I'm still only prototyping, so I know I'm always passing in a valid string. Though, I see your point - once the interface is out there and other devs start to use it. Once you said this I was more worried about the "caller" param. I'm passing in "this", but again, who knows what someone else might do. FWIW - I also want to acknowledge the above timeStampPattern issue: "DD" is invalid, and I have changed this to "dd" - but that still doesn't help my problem of an empty log file. :( I'll try example solution as you suggest.

Comment: FYI, the reason I suggested that is that there is an issue that if a null ExtendedProperty value is passed in an exception is raised (and swallowed) and the message will not be logged.

Comment: You are the man! You're exactly right! I had other ExtendedProperties I was setting (the "..." in above Write method) that I checked (after my earlier reply, of course) and one of them was null.  I did as you recommended and put a ?? string.Empty after it and it is magically logging to the file!  Thank you. How can I mark as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://lab.codeplex.com/workitem/3) with the Logging Application Block where if an ExtendedProperty value is null then the entry LogEntry will fail and not be logged.

Try changing your code to write an empty string if null is passed in for any of the ExtendedProperty values.  For example:

```
entry.ExtendedProperties.Add("Method", method ?? String.Empty);
```

This should avoid hitting the issue.